# (PHP) How do i refer a specific array value in a checkbox?

Tags: php

How do i refer a specific value in a checkbox array? I am trying to create a web page that shows an echo message when the user clicked one or multiple checkboxes.

Example :

HTML PAGE

[ ] pen

[x] pencil

[x] eraser

[ ] ruler

[submit button]

Output :

- you need pencil
- you need eraser

So here is what i came up with :

HTML

```
    <form action="email.php" method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="pen"> pen <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="pencil"> pencil <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="eraser"> eraser <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="ruler"> ruler <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> <br>
</form>
```

PHP

```
    <?php

$need = $_POST['options'];

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['options'])){

      if($need == "pen"){
        echo "you need pen ";
      }

      elseif($need == "pencil"){
        echo "you need pencil";
      }

      elseif($need == "eraser"){
        echo "you need eraser";
      }

      elseif($need == "ruler"){
        echo "you picked ruler";
      }
    else{
      echo "you must pick atleast one";
    }
  }
}
 ?>
```

Based on my code, where did i go wrong? and is there a better way to do this?

I'm still new to php and in stackoverflow so apologies for my mistakes.

Comment: what was the error then ?

Comment: you can use `in_array` like this `if(in_array('pen', $_POST['options'])){
            echo 'cool';
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code you did in PHP is that `$_POST['options']` will be an array type. so in order to make this work the code should be

```
 <?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $need = $_POST['options']; 
    if(!empty($need)){
       foreach($need as $n){
              if($n == "pen"){
                echo "you need pen ";
               }

             if($n == "pencil"){
                echo "you need pencil";
              }

            if($n == "eraser"){
               echo "you need eraser";
              }

            if($n == "ruler"){
                echo "you picked ruler";
              }

        }

  }
   else{
       echo "you must pick atleast one";
  }
}

 ?>
```

Try this, this should work.

> notice that I also changes the elseif to if to get all the selected options